# React access parent's dom node from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a grid component as follow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Action from './action.jsx';

class Grid extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.maxN = 110;
        this.tempArray = [];
        this.question;
    }

    getRandomN() {
        var randomN = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.maxN) + 1);

        if(this.tempArray.indexOf(randomN) === -1) {
            this.tempArray.push(randomN);
        }
        else {
            randomN = this.getRandomN();
        }

        return randomN;
    }

    getRandomQuestion() {   
        this.question = this.props.current.data.questions[this.getRandomN()];
        return this.question;
    }

    render() {
        this.getRandomQuestion();

        return (
            <section className="game">
                <div className="grid">

                    <div className="row">
                        <div ref="n1"></div>
                        <div ref="n2"></div>
                        <div ref="n3"></div>
                        <div ref="n4"></div>
                        <div ref="n5"></div>
                        <div ref="n6"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="row">
                        <div ref="n7"></div>
                        <div ref="n8"></div>
                        <div ref="n9"></div>
                        <div ref="n10"></div>
                        <div ref="n11"></div>
                        <div ref="n12"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="row">
                        <div ref="n13"></div>
                        <div ref="n14"></div>
                        <div ref="n15"></div>
                        <div ref="n16"></div>
                        <div ref="n17"></div>
                        <div ref="n18"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="row">
                        <div ref="n19"></div>
                        <div ref="n20"></div>
                        <div ref="n21"></div>
                        <div ref="n22"></div>
                        <div ref="n23"></div>
                        <div ref="n24"></div>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <Action question={this.question} getRandomQuestion={this.getRandomQuestion.bind(this)}/>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

inside the "Action" component, based on the correct or wrong answer coming from "getNewQuestion" I need to access a random grid element from the grid component. (any random going from "n1" to "n24" as assigned to each ref attribute)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Action extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            question: props.question
        }
    }

    getNewQuestion(e) {
        console.log(this.state.question.correct_option);

        let answerId = "option_" + this.state.question.correct_option;

        if(e.target.getAttribute('data-question') == answerId) {
            this.setState({
                question: this.props.getRandomQuestion()
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('wrong');

            React.findDOMNode(this.refs.n1).classList.add('fdsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsdf');
        }
    }

    render() {
        let state = this.state;

        return(
            <div className="action">
                <div className="action-question">
                    <h3>{state.question.question}</h3>
                </div>

                <div className="action-answers">
                    <p data-question="option_1" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_1}</p>
                    <p data-question="option_2" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_2}</p>
                    <p data-question="option_3" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_3}</p>
                    <p data-question="option_4" onClick={this.getNewQuestion.bind(this)}>{state.question.option_4}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}   

export default Action;
```

inside the "if" statment of the "getNewQuestion" I would like to do something like:

n2.classList.addClass('hidden');

I can't figure out how to access a parent's dom node from the "Action" component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the child really need to access the parent DOM directly? Shouldn't the parent Component know how to present itself? If so, then you can use callbacks that you pass down to the children, so that the children have the possibility to notify the parent when it should change.

```
const Child = ({modifyParent}) => (
  <div onClick={ modifyParent } >Click me!</div>
);

const Parent = () => {
  const modifyMyOwnStyle = event => {
    // here you have easy access 
    // if you want to style the parent.
    alert('Modifying style, based on child call');
  }

  return (
    <Child modifyParent={ modifyMyOwnStyle }/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Runnable JSFiddle demo** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/kzwck4j3/)

Comment: How would I access the single dome node from the parent (<div ref="n1"></div>) to be able to add a class of "hidden" for example?

Comment: Your div could, for example, have a class that depends on the parent state. Like so `<div className={  this.state.someVariable } />`.  Then you would alter that state inside on the `modifyMyOwnStyle` function. (Something like `this.setState({ someVariable: 'hidden' })`.  That should cause a re-render when the state has been updated. And then the `{ this.state.someVariable }` will resolve to the new value, changing which className is given to the div. **NOTE** that in my example I'm using functional components, which don't have state. So you'll have to convert them to stateful components.

Comment: Hi I agree with you, but wouldn't it be expensive (performance wise) to have a state for every singe grid element (there are 24 of them)...

Comment: It's more expensive. But I don't think it would even be noticeable until we were talking about tens of thousands. So worrying too much about that may be a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ref of a component and pass this to its children like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div ref={node => this.node = node}>
      <SomeChild parent={this.node} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

However I have to say that doing this is usually a bad idea, and I would reconsider if you really need to pass the node, or if there is another way around the problem.

EDIT: As jonahe's comment shows you can usually get around the problem by passing a callback to the child component that you can fire when something needs to happen in the parent component

Comment: This doesn't seem to work -- the ref isn't available until rendering is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Better than accessing parent's DOM node directly, you can use a callback prop that does it for you.

Something like:

```
class Grid extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.accessRandomElement = this.accessRandomElement.bind(this)
  }

  accessRandomElement() {
    // do you thing
  }

  render() {
    this.getRandomQuestion()

    return (
      <section className="game">
        ...
        <Action
          question={this.question}
          onAccessYourRandomElement={this.accessRandomElement}
          ///
        />
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

and then from inside Action you call `this.props.onAccessYourRandomElement()`